# Combining tagging with ntheorem

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I would like to combine the `tagging` package with `ntheorem` to obtain `ntheorem`-environments that are tagged. A minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tagging}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

%\usetag{DefTag}
\droptag{DefTag}

\newenvironment{TaggedDef}{ %
    \begin{taggedblock}{DefTag} %
        \begin{Def} %
}
{
        \end{Def} %
    \end{taggedblock} %
}

\begin{document}


\begin{TaggedDef}
Test
\end{TaggedDef}

\begin{taggedblock}{DefTag}
\begin{Def}
    Test
\end{Def}
\end{taggedblock}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the first Test does not work. I obtain the error message:

```
\begin{TaggedDef} on input line 21 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

The second Test works fine and the first Test works also fine, if one replaces the `\droptag{DefTag}` by `\usetag{DefTag}`.

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to nest environments that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the commands associated to the environments (I also added an optional argument to `TaggedDef` to keep the optional argument for `Def` but this, of course, it's optional):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tagging}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\usetag{DefTag}
%\droptag{DefTag}

\newenvironment{TaggedDef}[1][]{%
    \taggedblock{DefTag}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\Def}{\Def[#1]}%
}
{%
        \endDef%
    \endtaggedblock%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{TaggedDef}
Test.
\end{TaggedDef}

\begin{TaggedDef}[An important definition]
Test.
\end{TaggedDef}

\end{document}
```

[image]